# Which is the best way to do end to end testing of Spring Boot Rest APIs?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have checked in google and stackoverflow for end to end testing of Spring Boot Rest APIs.

I would like to test  controller -> Service -> Repository at once.

I found two approaches are efficient:

```
1. TestRestTemplate: 
   Single call to the controller method with in-memory database configuration for repository.
2. MockMvc: 
   Create 2 Test classes. 
   one for Controller->Service 
   and one for Service->Repository. 
   Is there any way to club both 2 classes into one class.
```

which is the best way to do "end to end testing" of Spring Boot Rest APIs from above 2 approaches ???

Comment: Rest assured (http://rest-assured.io/)  could be considered as an option if you would like to test the APIS by hitting the http endpoint

Comment: Search for integration testing of REST APIs. The things you're looking at are for unit testing individual aspects of the service. If you're looking to do tests for 'everything at once', integration tests are it.

Comment: From the above 2 approaches (TestRestTemplate, MockMvc) which is the best one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the better way to do the ***END2END*** testing is to use TestRestTemplate. It would actually start-up the server at a random port (it you configured) and call the api itself for testing.In this way, it mimic the actual behavior of the running server and use the default configures and beans.

MockMvc, in my testing experience, is mainly for testing the web layer, aka controllers. I would use mocked Service beans to replace the original ones. So I can test the behaviors of the controller layer itself without having to worry about the bugs in the service layer. More importantly, I don't have to set up any Database before testing.

So I would say, for E2E test, you can go for the first approach.